# How to correctly measure timing of http request on java

Tags: java, http, amazon-web-services, apache-httpclient-4.x, aws-lambda

I need to better measure the detailed timing of a HTTP Request (connection time, time to first byte, transfer time).

Context:
I have a small java app (running on AWS Lambda) that is calling a third party service.
As the logging was showing big delays in the processing, a small piece of logging was added to better find out where the delays was happening:

```java
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://www.google.com");
HttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
HttpResponse baseResponse = internalClient.execute(request);
long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```

While `duration` registers something like 30 seconds, the provider logs shows 1.5 seconds!

So I wonder where is the time being spent? How can this be measured?

Update: An example of the data I would like to have that is possible using cURL: https://blog.josephscott.org/2011/10/14/timing-details-with-curl/

Comment: *"Is there a java http/request library"* [4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a software library are off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I can change the phrasing: "Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." and I did just that.

Answer (score 0):

To precisely measure elapsed time in Java use `nanoTime()` As stated in the docs [System.nanoTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()):

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not
>   related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value
>   returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin
>   time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). The same
>   origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a
>   Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to
>   use a different origin.

Note that if you need to compare time elapsed between calls in different threads, you must use `currentTimeMillis`, as `nanoTime` is not thread safe.

**Edit:**

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18466249/999516)

The request execution is terminated when the headers are received, body message is later associated with the entity when fully resolved:

```
EntityUtils.consume(baseResponse.getEntity());
```

Comment: The problem is to measure the time inside of the HTTP request: connection time, time to first byte, transfer time. The request is to be made in one thread (unless httpClient starts new threads by itself).

Comment: Interesting. So I could actually at least have 2 separate timings: connection and TTFB and with the consume, the transmission time.

Comment: @upsfeup that's correct. Consider to accept the answer if it solved your problem or, at least, this particular question.

Comment: @upsfeup Do you use the timestamp directly after execute(..) for the calculation of TTFB ? I think this is not the exact curl equivalent as for example HTTP headers are already parsed which is not the case for curl time_starttransfer